# How do I use string.replace() with chars?

Tags: c#, tostring

So full disclousre this is homework. Anyway trying to make a morse code converter and I am just stuck on this last issue. I want to use chars and then use string.replace but I can't since my dictionary is all strings. I want to use chars though. So how would I get around this?

```
public void InputReader()
{
    string inputForTranslating = inputForTranslator.Text;

    Dictionary<string, string> morseDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { " ", " " }, { ",", "--..--" }, { ".", ".-.-.-" }, { "\\?", "..--.." }, { "0", "-----" }, { "1", ".----" }, { "2", "..---" }, { "3", "...--" },
        { "4", "....-" }, { "5", "....." }, { "6", "-...." }, { "7", "--..." }, { "8", "---.." }, { "9", "----." }, { "A", ".-" },
        { "B", "-..." }, { "C", "-.-." }, { "D", "-.." }, { "E", "." }, { "F", "..-." }, { "G", "--." }, { "H", "...." }, { "I", ".." },
        { "J", ".---" }, { "K", "-.-" }, { "L", ".-.." }, { "M", "---" }, { "N", "-." }, { "O", "---" }, { "P", ".--." }, { "Q", "--.-" },
        { "R", ".-." }, { "S", "..." }, { "T", "-" }, { "U", "..-" }, { "V", "...-" }, { "W", ".--" }, { "X", "-..-" }, { "Y", "-.--" },
        { "Z", "--.." }
    };

    char[] charArray = inputForTranslating.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
    {

        outPutTranslation.Text = outPutTranslation.ToString().Replace(morseDictionary.Keys, morseDictionary.Values); ////This is where the error occurs "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>.KeyCollection' to 'char'"
    }
}
```

Comment: `outPutTranslation.ToString()` - Assuming outPutTranslation is some sort of control, this is not correct. I assume it's supposed to hold the Morse code version of whatever was entered in inputForTranslator?

Comment: `char`s for what?

Answer (score 1):

Replace takes strings/chars as parameters, not a collection of keys or values. 
In this case, you don't even need the `Replace`, you can just add the values based on the keys.
Also, your `outPutTranslation.Text` will only have the last char.

```
Dictionary<string, string> morseDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { " ", " " }, { ",", "--..--" }, { ".", ".-.-.-" }, { "\\?", "..--.." }, { "0", "-----" }, { "1", ".----" }, { "2", "..---" }, { "3", "...--" },
    { "4", "....-" }, { "5", "....." }, { "6", "-...." }, { "7", "--..." }, { "8", "---.." }, { "9", "----." }, { "A", ".-" },
    { "B", "-..." }, { "C", "-.-." }, { "D", "-.." }, { "E", "." }, { "F", "..-." }, { "G", "--." }, { "H", "...." }, { "I", ".." },
    { "J", ".---" }, { "K", "-.-" }, { "L", ".-.." }, { "M", "---" }, { "N", "-." }, { "O", "---" }, { "P", ".--." }, { "Q", "--.-" },
    { "R", ".-." }, { "S", "..." }, { "T", "-" }, { "U", "..-" }, { "V", "...-" }, { "W", ".--" }, { "X", "-..-" }, { "Y", "-.--" },
    { "Z", "--.." }
};

string output = "";

foreach (char c in inputForTranslating.ToCharArray())
{
    output += morseDictionary[c];
}

outPutTranslation.Text = output;
```

Comment: You would need to .ToString() `c`, since the key is a string, or change the Dictionary to Dictionary<char, string>. From your code, a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RFx46X

Answer (score 0):

Well, `string.Replace()` works both with two chars or two strings. The error clearly states that `morseDictionary.Keys` is not a string. Neither is `morseDictionary.Values`. And it's right, they are the list of keys and values of the dictionary!

There's another mistake in that code. You're converting your input to a char array, and then iterating each character, and trying to replace there. Think about what it's doing:

If you have `-.-`, in the first iteration you will search over `-`, in the second over `.` and lastly over `-`. You'll never be able to find the `K`.

You should iterate your dictionary, and search each word in the whole string.

```
foreach(string key in morseDictionary) {     
    //for morse->letter   
    inputForTranslating=inputForTranslating.Replace(morseDictionary[key],key);
    //for letter->morse
    inputForTranslating=inputForTranslating.Replace(key,morseDictionary[key]);
```